# Oracle apex not working after installation http://localhost:8282/apex/apex_admin

Tags: oracle, localhost, oracle-apex

```
This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 8282 apex admin
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I have installed oracle apex 19.2 v but after successful installation it is not accessible.

Comment: What happens if you try `http://127.0.0.1:8282/apex/apex_admin` ?

Comment: same thing... i have also changed port... but invain.

Answer (score 1):

The ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error often is caused by not mapping the requested Port to anything, either ORDS, nor the Embedded PL/SQL Gateway (EPG).

Try to see if the right Port is conifgured

```
select dbms_xdb.gethttpport from dual;
```

Or set the right Port for the EPG

```
exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8282');
commit;
```

If you try to connect to APEX via a webserver, check if the Port of the webserver is configured correctly and if the webserver is able to reach the APEX Installation path.
Some webservers, e.g. Tomcat have a config setting for forcing HTTPS connections, if you have no ssl certificate, that could cause the problem.

If you running APEX on a locale installation, check your Firewall for preventing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue. This can be caused if the port which we mention is already in use by some other services. In my case `8282` was already in use.

I changed it to `8283` by

```
exec dbms_xdb.sethttpport('8283') ;
```

After this I tried to hit [the URL](http://localhost:8283/apex/apex_admin) and it worked perfectly.

[image: screenshot administration login page]